# How to draw a line around around points in a numpy array where the value is equal to a specific number

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a "line" or like contours around points/sections of an image where the pixel value(s) of those sections is equal to zero.

This is what I've tried but I don't get the desired output. What I get is just an image with a yellow rectangular box

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_image = Image.open(path_to_image).convert("L")
input_image_array = np.asarray(input_image).astype(np.uint8)

zero_indices = np.where(input_image_array == 0)

rows, cols = zero_indices[0], zero_indices[1]

input_image_array[rows[0]:rows[-1], cols[0]:cols[-1]] = 1

plt.imshow(input_image_array)
```

Any help will be much appreciated thanks!!

Comment: Contour finding is solved problem in opencv [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Comment: What your code is currently doing is drawing a rectangle where one corner is the first zero pixel and the other corner is the last zero pixel (though it actually stops one row and one column short). Drawing a contour is more involved.